# rust ...why import a function into a lib from an rs file? - failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `client`

Tags: rust

-src/
 -lib.rs
 -client.rs

Wow am I baffled by rust and their documentation.  Why rust are you not working with the below?

```
client.rs 

pub fn connect(x: usize) -> usize {
   return x
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_connect() {
        assert_eq!(connect(5), 5);
    }
}

cannot find function `connect` in this scope
```

lib.rs

```
mod client;

pub fn fu() -> usize {
    let really = client::connect(5);
    return really
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_fu() {
        assert_eq!(fu(),5);
    }

}

cannot find function `fu` in this scope




cargo test

error[E0425]: cannot find function `connect` in this scope
  --> src/client.rs:12:20
   |
12 |         assert_eq!(connect(5), 5);
   |                    ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this function
   |
11 |     use crate::client::connect;
   |

error[E0425]: cannot find function `fu` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:17:20
   |
17 |         assert_eq!(fu(),5);
   |                    ^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this function
   |
11 |     use crate::fu;
   |

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `test` module for the test. You need to bring the outer module in the scope. You can use `super` to relate to it like this:

```
mod client;

pub fn fu() -> usize {
    let really = client::connect(5);
    return really
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*; // bring to scope every declared item from the outer (lib) module

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_fu() {
        assert_eq!(fu(),5);
    }

}
```